# How to add a Progress bar for $http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I want to add a loading bar or loading animation on the whole page until the data is being fetched from Mongo database into the web application through $http request.

I have looked into XMLHTTP request which has this feature straight away but I want to use $http.

My code looks like this

```
$http.post("/someroute", someData)
.then(function(res) {
   $scope.variable = res.data;
   $(".webcontent").css("display", "block");
})
```

I want to make sure that I don't reveal the unformatted page to the user while opening my web application. The scope variable is used to populate template using ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `eventHandlers` to be attached to the underlying `XMLHttpRequest`. I've not tested it, but something like this should work:

```
$http.post("/someroute", someData, {
  eventHandlers: {
    progress: function(progressEvent) {
      // update progress bar
    }
  }
})
```

Note that the event handler is run inside the digest loop as you'd expect with AngularJS.

The event you get is a [`ProgressEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ProgressEvent), from which you could compute a percentage.